# How can i get error message from backend router?

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, react-native, jwt

Run the /kakao/getpost router through the getpost function. At this time, the token is checked through authenticateToken. If the token expires and the if (err) {} conditional statement is executed, the /getpost router receives err again, the if(err) conditional statement is executed, and I want to receive an error message from the front as data. like console.log(data)

but if i use my code

this error occure

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

how can i fix my code?

this is ym code

```
            const getpost = async () => {
      
              const {data} = await axios.post(
                '/kakao/getpost',
                {refreshToken: refreshToken, kakaoid: me.id},
                {
                  headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${kakaoaccesstoken}`},
                },
              );

              console.log('data", data)
            };




   exports.authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
              const authHeader = 
 req.headers["authorization"];

              const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];

              if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);

              jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
                console.log(err);
                if (err) {
                  console.log("err:::::::::::", err);
                  return res.sendStatus(403);
                  // next(err);
                }
                req.user = user;
                next();
              });
            };




   router.post("/getpost", authenticateToken, async 
   (req, res, next) => {
              try {
                console.log("getpost");
                if (err) {
                
                  return res.status(403).json("err");
                }
              } catch (error) {
                next(error); // status 500
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to throw in if condition not return.

```
   router.post("/getpost", authenticateToken, async 
   (req, res, next) => {
              try {
                console.log("getpost");
                if (err) {                    
                  throw err;
                }
              } catch (error) {
                next(error); // status 500
              }
            });
```